# Concurrent access using cursor

Tags: java, android, sms, cursor, android-contentprovider

I am writing an Android SMS App. I am reading already existing SMS-es using "content://sms/inbox" (I know it is undocumented). I want to know how concurrent access is handled?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null,null);
mCursor.moveToFirst();
//I display the first sms. The code is not shown here.
//As the user scrolls the SMS-es other SMS-es are shown
//by moving the cursor
```

I have a problem with this code. SMS-es can be deleted by other apps which have the requisite permission. What will happen to the cursor if other SMS apps delete the SMS which is pointed to by my cursor. For e.g., assume that I have 10 SMSes (latest is the first) and my cursor is at the 9th SMS. Some other SMS app deletes the last 3 SMSes. Does not this make my cursor dangling?

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
//read the fields. What if somebody deletes the SMS-es
//after moveToNext evaluates to true but before I read fields?
}
```

I think all the rows in the result set are not cached and this poses a problem.

Comment: Save cursor data to an object, close cursor and work with saved data. Listen to changes and re-fresh data every time.